# SSRS Report Default Values Blank

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

So, I'm having trouble with default values. I will preface by saying I'm using a separate dataset for default values.

Parameter 1 and 2: Start and End

Parameter 3 looks for teams (Team Red, Team Blue, etc)

Parameter 4 looks for people in said team (who have registered between start and end).

I have default values on Parameter 4 (for team leads), which work fine sometimes. Let's say Cody, Kyle, and Brittany (who are also my default values) are registered within the start and end time of a year. The defaults work fine.

However, when I change the start and end time to only a month and only Kyle and Brittany come back for Parameter 4, the defaults values do not come back at all (despite there still being two default values)

In short, default values only work when ALL names are in the Parameter 4. The weird thing is that it works locally on my PC, but when it's uploaded to SSRS, the issue starts. Is this just something that SSRS just does not allow? I've tried deleting and uploading the report (since I know there can be cache issues).

Here's the query for parameter 4:

```
SELECT 
    Distinct
    UserName,
    UserID
FROM USERS AS A
LEFT JOIN UserRegister B on A.UserID = B.UserID

WHERE (B.Start between @Start and @End) and TeamID in @Team
```

Here's my default values query:

```
SELECT 
    Distinct
    UserName,
    UserID
FROM USERS AS A

WHERE UserID in (
    317566, --Cody
    57975, --Kyle
    116, --Brittany)
```

Comment: Default values are only applied once when the parameters are loaded. It does not re-check for defaults each time you change the first few parameter values.

Comment: Can you add the JOIN and Start date clause to the Default values query? I'm don't remember if that will force it to run again when the values change.

Comment: @HannoverFist I tried that, but it didn't make a difference. :(

Comment: Is it a multi select parameter? I have similar setup.. but it seems to work if it is a multi select parameter. Most of the time anyway.